# Error installing jython on mac os x

Tags: java, macos, jython

I'm trying to run jython-installer-2.5.3.jar on mac os x and I'm getting:

```
java -jar jython-installer-2.7-b3.jar 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.cli.Options.setSortAsAdded(Z)V
at org.python.util.install.InstallerCommandLine.createOptions(InstallerCommandLine.java:397)
at org.python.util.install.InstallerCommandLine.<init>(InstallerCommandLine.java:121)
at org.python.util.install.Installation.internalMain(Installation.java:371)
at org.python.util.install.Installation.main(Installation.java:43)
```

I've tried it with java 1.6 and java 1.7 with the same results on OS X snow leopard and just updated to yosemite also with same results.

There are almost no references to this issue on jython mailing lists or searching through google. 
Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: I've had this same problem running yosemite. I also tried installing from homebrew with the same error.